# Have column display group's value

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that pulls data similar to the one in the below table

```
incident_type   zone    seconds data_category   data_type
Alarm           East    30      A               1
Alarm           East    90      A               2
Alarm           East    120     B               1
Alarm           East    180     C               1
Alarm           West    30      A               1
Alarm           West    90      A               2
Alarm           West    120     B               1
Alarm           West    180     C               1
Warning         East    30      A               1
Warning         East    90      A               2
Warning         East    120     B               1
Warning         East    180     C               1
Warning         West    30      A               1
Warning         West    90      A               2
Warning         West    120     B               1
Warning         West    180     C               1
```

What I want to do is display it like so:

```
Alarm    East    West
A  1     30      30
A  2     90      90      
B  1     120     120     
C  1     180     180    

Warning  East    West
A  1     30      30
A  2     90      90      
B  1     120     120     
C  1     180     180
```

So, I set up my Tablix with the following groups

[image]

As you can see I have the data grouped in a way that breaks the data up correctly. However, the resulting tables look like this

```
Alarm    East    West
A  1     30      30
A  2     90      90      
B  1     120     120     
C  1     180     180    

Alarm    East    West
A  1     30      30
A  2     90      90      
B  1     120     120     
C  1     180     180
```

As you can see, "Alarm" is repeated for the header. How can I get the value for `[incident_type]` to be the correct value in relation to the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `incident_type` group is not set to be a header group.

Delete `incident_type` group and right click `data_category` group, select `Add Group` / `Parent Group...`. A window will pop up, set Add group header and select `incident_type` field.

[image]

After that, a new column will be added to the beginning of your tablix, delete that column and the required rows to leave this:

[image]

Merge the first two cells in the first row for the `incident_type` and you will get the desired output.

Let me know if this helps.